# Using the first host in group

Tags: ansible

My ansible host definition looks like

```
[elasticclient]
192.168.10.2
192.168.10.3
```

I want to use the first host in the group to be used in a variable. My playbook is

```
- hosts: kibana
  roles:
    - kibana
  vars:
    kibana_elasticsearch_url: http://{{ groups[['elasticclient'][0]] }}:9200
```

When I run this, my file contains

```
http://[u'192.168.10.2']:9200
```

How do I change it to

```
http://192.168.10.2:9200
```

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out, it was a list and I had to index it again.

```
kibana_elasticsearch_url: http://{{ groups['elasticproxy'][0] }}:9200
```

Comment: In this expression `groups[['elasticproxy'][0]]` you take string `'elasticproxy'`, make array of single element with `['elasticsearch']`, then take first element of it `['elasticsearch'][0]`, which effectively is `'elasticproxy'`. So why not just use `groups['elasticproxy']`?

Comment: Thanks Konstantin I edited his answer to include your simplification

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use what ansible provides as default: 
`hostvars[groups['elasticsearch'][0]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']`

Answer (score 1):

```
groups['elasticproxy'] | first
```

or

```
groups['elasticproxy'][0]
```

will both do the trick.